# Getting SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple. Facing this issue when I was using cv2.putText. How to fix this error?

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to print the detected object's category type over its image. Then I first calculate approx from approxPolyDp() then saved the length of approx into object_corner.
I got coordinates of x, y, weight, and height using boundingReact() but when I tried to print text over the detected object's image then facing SystemError.

```
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*contour_perimeter, True)
        object_corner = len(approx)
        x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(approx)

        cv2.rectangle(imgContour, (x, y), (x+width, y+height), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(imgContour, objectType,(x+(width//2)-10), (y+(height//2)-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.5,(0,0,0),2)
```

Comment: What is the exact error message and to which line does it point (mark as comment in the code)? It would also help if you could provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the error.

Comment: Thanks, @bjhend for giving me feedback regarding the minimal example. I am getting SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple as an error message when I was using putText()

Comment: check types of imgContour, objectType, ... your code is incomplete, it does not show these things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the last line of code cv.putText().
The correct code should look like

```
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*contour_perimeter, True)
    object_corner = len(approx)
    x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(approx)

    cv2.rectangle(imgContour, (x, y), (x+width, y+height), (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv2.putText(imgContour, objectType,(x+(width//2)-10), (y+(height//2)-10), 
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.5,(0,0,0),2)
```